# How to set global variable within one function and have it accessed by another?

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I am trying to make is so that when you click 'set' it will set the scroll variable position. When you click return I want it to change the scroll position to where it was last 'set'.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qt2xxhtd/

HTML:

```
<div class="set">Set</div>
<div class="last">Return</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

CSS:

```
div.set{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
}
div.last{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    top: 80px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$('div.set').click(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});

$('div.last').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(scroll);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$('div.set').click(function(){
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // Don't use var here...
});

$('div.last').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(scroll);
});
```

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/yd8dpgn2/

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `var` keyword in the function. That will keep the code from creating a local variable in the function, so that it uses the global variable instead:

```
$('div.set').click(function(){
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```